# Rational approximation of rational exponentiation root with error control

Tags: algorithm, math, exponent, approximation, rational-number

I am looking for an algorithm that would efficiently calculate `b^e` where `b` and `e` are rational numbers, ensuring that the approximation error won't exceed given `err` (rational as well). Explicitly, I am looking for a function:

```
rational exp(rational base, rational exp, rational err)
```

that would preserve law `|exp(b, e, err) - b^e| < err`

Rational numbers are represented as pairs of big integers. Let's assume that all rationality preserving operations like addition, multiplication etc. are already defined.

I have found several approaches, but they did not allow me to control the error clearly enough. In this problem I don't care about integer overflow. What is the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: Well, one obvious answer is to use exact rational arithmetic, in which case the error is zero. I presume you are hoping to find the best performing algorithm that still obeys the error bound given.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Not so obvious given that `2^0.5` is not rational.  The error is required.

Comment: @btilly: Oops, I forgot that exponent can also be rational. My bad.

Comment: Your problem would be much easier if the requirement were a relative precision (such as a given number of significant digits) rather than the absolute precision you now require.

Comment: Trying to exponentiate rational numbers pushes beyond the bounds where rational arithmetic is usually useful. Since you are not going to get an exact result, why not just use [GMP](https://gmplib.org) and [MPFR](https://www.mpfr.org) to get a result as accurate as you desire? Any finite floating-point number is a rational number, so that satisfies the problem you have stated.

Comment: My language does not and will never support traditional floats. I may steal their algorithms, but I need error control

Answer (score 1):

This one is complicated, so I'm going to outline the approach that I'd take.  I do not promise no errors, and you'll have a lot of work left.

I will change variables from what you said to `exp(x, y, err)` to be `x^y` within error `err`.If `y` is not in the range `0 <= y < 1`, then we can easily multiply by an appropriate `x^k` with `k` an integer to make it so.  So we only need to worry about fractional `y

If all numerators and denominators were small, it would be easy to tackle this by first taking an integer power, and then taking a root using Newton's method.  But that naive idea will fall apart painfully when you try to estimate something like `(1000001/1000000)^(2000001/1000000)`.  So the challenge is to keep that from blowing up on you.

I would recommend looking at the problem of calculating `x^y` as `x^y = (x0^y0) * (x0^(y-y0)) * (x/x0)^y = (x0^y0) * e^((y-y0) * log(x0)) * e^(y * log(x/x0))`.  And we will choose `x0` and `y0` such that the calculations are easier and the errors are bounded.

To bound the errors, we can first come up with a naive upper bound `b` on `x0^y0` - something like "next highest integer than `x` to the power of the next highest integer than `y`".  We will pick `x0` and `y0` to be close enough to `x` and `y` that the latter terms are under `2`.  And then we just need to have the three terms estimated to within `err/12`, `err/(6*b)` and `err/(6*b)`.  (You might want to make those errors tighter half that then make the final answer a nearby rational.)

Now when we pick `x0` and `y0` we will be aiming for "close rational with smallish numerator/denominator".  For that we start calculating the [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction).  This gives a sequence of rational numbers that quickly converges to a target real.  If we just cut off the sequence fairly soon, we can quickly find a rational number that is within any desired distance of a target real while keeping relatively small numerators and denominators.

Let's work from the third term backwards.

We want `y * log(x/x0) < log(2)`.  But from the Taylor series if `x/2 < x0 < 2x` then `log(x/x0) < x/x0 - 1`.  So we can search the continued fraction for an appropriate `x0`.

Once we have found it, we can use the Taylor series for `log(1+z)` to calculate `log(x/x0)` to within `err/(12*y*b)`.  And then the Taylor series for `e^z` to calculate the term to our desired error.

The second term is more complicated.  We need to estimate `log(x0)`.  What we do is find an appropriate integer `k` such that `1.1^k <= x0 < 1.1^(k+1)`.  And then we can estimate both `k * log(1.1)` and `log(x0 / 1.1^k)` fairly precisely.  Find a naive upper bound to that `log` and use it to find a close enough `y0` for the second term to be within 2.  And then use the Taylor series to estimate `e^((y-y0) * log(x0))` to our desired precision.

For the first term we use the naive method of raising `x0` to an integer and then Newton's method to take a root, to give `x0^y0` to our desired precision.

Then multiply them together, and we have an answer.  (If you chose the "tighter errors, nicer answer", then now you'd do a continued fraction on that answer to pick a better rational to return.)